# How to use iptables to rewrite DNS queries flowing through a wireguard vpn?

Tags: linux, iptables, vpn

I have a wireguard VPN server I had to rebuild. The old server had an internal DNS server running on a virtual interface, `172.16.0.1`. I don't really need/want to run DNS on this, is there a way I can use iptables to intercept DNS queries to `172.16.0.1` and send them to `1.1.1.1` instead?

ifconfig:

```
wg0: flags=209<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1420
        inet 10.19.49.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.19.49.1

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Here's my postup/down rules in wireguard:

```
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's pretty simple:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dst 172.16.0.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:53
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dst 172.16.0.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:53

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED,DNAT -j ACCEPT
```

Better use the `iptables-save/iptables-restore/iptables-apply` instead script that runs `iptables` directly multiple times. Use `iptables-persistent` package to make the rules permanent.

To better understand of the `iptables` you can read [the iptables tutorial](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/iptables-tutorial.html).

Comment: In case you will try to communicate directly on the machine you have to add (next to mentioned rules): ```iptables -t nat OUTPUT -p tcp --dst 172.16.0.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:53``` and ```iptables -t nat OUTPUT -p udp --dst 172.16.0.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 1.1.1.1:53``` as traffic originated directly on the machine is not "match" **PREROUTING** but **OUTPUT**.

Comment: As I've understood from question, topic starter means rules for VPN server, not end host. So DNS traffic is forwarded, not local-originated.

Comment: "I have a wireguard VPN server I had to rebuild."  The comment was just in case. I can imagine that with rebuild there can be restored some scripts for any reason. At that moment there can be mentioned the IP of the server. But it is more like "to be safe" :-).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, previously we were using Algo with IpSec, but wireguard is way simpler to manage, so we switched. Problem is everyone's deployed vpn configs want to use that dns server, which doesn't exist anymore.